# Fourier: Zero expansion of Cosine

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, exponential-function, fourier-transform, trigonometric-integrals

I must calculate  the fourier transform of $\cos(2\pi t)$ in the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$. Here I show all what I have done:

[image: ALL STEPS SHOWN]

I am stuck at the end, thanks in advance.

Note: I am sorry, I have provided an image because I do not know how to use latex to write such complex functions :'(

Comment: http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/sinusoids.php

Comment: @hrt yes, I saw that, but in equation 2 I do not see how they arrive from line 2 to line 3...

Comment: They do explain it in the paragraph below, linking to another page.